# How long does PostMessage() take to send to HWND_BROADCAST?

Tags: winapi, keyhook

I am using the standard winapi low-level keyboard hook mechanism in a small C program, which acts as an invisible server app. When the hook proc detects certain keystrokes it broadcasts a custom message to all my client apps which are listening for these alerts.  It is all working well in dev.

My question is about using PostMessage() with HWND_BROADCAST inside the hook proc. When I use a low-level keyboard hook in my dotnet apps it gets silently unhooked after a few hours.  I'm guessing this is because the dotnet garbage collector is doing a full GC at the wrong moment. So instead of trying to improve my dotnet code I have moved the hook entirely into a separate C program, which is working well in test.

But I don't want to go down this route, only to find that PostMessage() with HWND_BROADCAST is taking too long.  Does anyone know how long PostMessage() takes to post a message to all top-level windows?  And will this timing degrade if a system is fully loaded, with more app instances and top-level windows?  I don't want to encounter the issue I had with dotnet apps where the hook proc takes too long and windows silently unhooks it.

Thanks,

Comment: It doesn't take very long at all to post a message into a message queue. `PostMessage()` doesn't wait for the message to be broadcasted.  That being said, why not use a more targeted approach? Post the message only to specific windows that actually want the message. Or use an IPC channel such as a named pipe or socket server.

Comment: This is a bit like, "How long is a piece of string?" As Remy already said, the *call* doesn't take long at all, because it returns asynchronously (almost immediately). But how long it takes to *deliver* the message to all, top-level windows will (unsurprisingly) depend on how many top-level windows there are.

Comment: That's good news, thanks both.  So PostMessage timing to return to the hook proc shouldnt change no matter how many apps are running.  Yes, targetted messaging would be better, and could be made more secure.

Comment: The API you are looking for is [`SendMessageTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagetimeoutw). It allows you to observe the outcome of sending a message and won't tie the calling thread to the demise of the receiving thread.

Comment: @IInspectable that is not a good idea in this case. That waits for every window to respond (not very useful in a broadcast) or to timeout. The more windows there are, the longer it can take to run (the documentation says as much). And hooks have a very short time to run

Answer (score 0):

According to Remy Lebeau's recommendations:

It doesn't take very long at all to post a message into a message queue. `PostMessage()` doesn't wait for the message to be broadcasted. And targeted messaging would be better and could be made more secure.